# Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard, .Net Core 2.0 : Issue while getting 'objectGUID' value from Active Directory

Tags: .net, active-directory

I am using .Net Core 2.0 and Novell.Directory.Ldap.NETStandard 2.3.8 and used the following code to get User resource attributes from active directory.
I am getting values for all attributes except for objectGUID where I am getting some garbage value.

```
LdapEntry userEntry = ldapConn.Read(dn);
LdapAttribute uid = userEntry?.getAttribute("objectGUID");
```

Output:

```
{LdapAttribute: {type='objectGUID', value='�� ���E�1���Ѕv'}}
```

There are no issues if I use LDAP as a backend entity.

When I used below code to get Guid, I got following error.
new `Guid(SupportClass.ToByteArray(userEntry.getAttribute("objectGuid").ByteValue)).ToString()`

Error:

```
'new Guid(SupportClass.ToByteArray(userEntry.getAttribute("objectGuid").ByteValue)).ToString()' threw an exception of type 'System.ArgumentException'
"Byte array for GUID must be exactly 16 bytes long.\r\nParameter name: b"
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a GUID format, so you can use the string value, and you should convert the byte values to the guid. Refer:

```
 var bytes = (byte[])(nextEntry.getAttribute("objectGUID").ByteValue as object);
 var guid = new Guid(bytes);
```

Hope this helps!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AVGMf.png)